# Boolean arguments issue when creating Settings activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, boolean

After creating an activity for a Settings page I noticed that, `mCurrentValue !== value` in `if (mCurrentValue !== value)` returned a warning:

> Identity equality for arguments of types Boolean? and Boolean can be unstable because of implicit boxing

I tried resolving this warning by adding a `?` next to `Boolean` in `override fun onXchange(value:Boolean) {`, but then the following error returned:

> 'onXchange' overrides nothing

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

**Activity class**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.MenuItem

class MySettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MySettingsFragment.PreferenceXchangeListener {
    private var mCurrentValue: Boolean? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        mCurrentValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("preference_a", false)
        if (mCurrentValue as Boolean)
        {
            setTheme(R.style.MyDarkAppCompatTheme)
        }
        else
        {
            setTheme(R.style.MyLightAppCompatTheme)
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mysettings)

        val settingsFragment = MySettingsFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, settingsFragment)
                .commit()

        val myActionBar = actionBar

        if (myActionBar != null)
        {
            myActionBar.setTitle(R.string.settings)
            myActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK))
            myActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            myActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
            myActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white, null))
        }
    }

    override fun onXchange(value:Boolean?) {
        if (mCurrentValue !== value) {
            mCurrentValue = value
            recreate()
        }
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val intent = parentActivityIntent
                intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                onBackPressed()
                return true
            }

            else ->
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)

        val mCheckBoxPreference = findPreference("preference_a") as CheckBoxPreference
        mCheckBoxPreference.onPreferenceChangeListener = this
    }

    private var mPreferenceXchangeListener: PreferenceXchangeListener? = null

    interface PreferenceXchangeListener {
        fun onXchange(value:Boolean)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try
        {
            mPreferenceXchangeListener = context as MySettingsFragment.PreferenceXchangeListener
        }
        catch (e:ClassCastException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach::::: PreferenceXchangeListener must be set in parent Activity")
        }
    }

    override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference, newValue:Any):Boolean {
        val preferenceKey = preference.key

        if (preferenceKey == "preference_a")
        {
            (preference as CheckBoxPreference).isChecked = newValue as Boolean

            mPreferenceXchangeListener!!.onXchange(newValue)
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MySettingsFragment::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want `!==` instead of `!=` ?  If you're just comparing two boolean values for equality then you can just use the latter (even if one is nullable and one isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first I can explain the issue it describes. Let's propose a very contrived scenario:

**BooleanProvider.java**

```
class BooleanProvider {
    @NonNull Boolean wrapMyBoolean(boolean state) {
        return new Boolean(state);
    }
}
```

**BooleanProviderTest.kt**

```
class BooleanProviderTest {
    @Test fun `it returns a true value when true is provided`() {
        assertSame(BooleanProvider().wrapMyBoolean(true), true)
    }
}
```

This test will actually fail, because the instances of `Boolean` are not the same. In the Java code, we initialized a new instance of `Boolean` (rather than the statically defined `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` instances that you'll get when a primitive is auto-boxed to a `java.lang.Boolean`). So to avoid a potential unexpected result, it is recommending that you don't compare these types by reference.

The simplest fix would be to just change your equality test to `!=` instead of `!==`. This would perform identity equality testing rather than reference equality testing, and will handle a null value on either side appropriately. This is what you want 99% of the time anyway.

Secondly, you can also just declare `mCurrentValue` as a non-null type, and give it a default value, if you don't need to handle a null value in a specific way. Just declare it as:

```
private var mCurrentValue: Boolean = false // false is the default here
```

Comment: can i have your email?